# Query Google Big Query Table by today's date

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have query pertaining to the google big query tables. We are currently looking to query the big query table based on the file uploaded on the day into the cloud storage.

Meaning:

I have to load the data into big query table based on every day's data into cloud storage.

When i query:

```sql
select * from BQT where load_date =<TODAY's DATE>
```

Can we achieve this without adding the date field into the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just don't want to add a date column, Append current date suffix to your table name like BQT_20200112 when the GCS file is uploaded.

Then you can query specific datetime table by `_TABLE_SUFFIX` syntax.

Below is example query using `_TABLE_SUFFIX`

```
SELECT
  field1,
  field2,
  field3
FROM
  `your_dataset.BQT_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20200112'
```

As you see, You don't need to add additional field like load_date when you query the tables using date suffix and wildcard symbol.

Comment: Assuming you only have one table, you are going to need to have the date someplace. If you don't want to have an explict date, maybe you could partition the table by date and then include the partition date in your query.